# typing variadic arguments in python

Tags: python

I wrote the following code:

```
def foo(a: List[str]):
  return a

def bar(*b: Tuple[str, ...]):
  return foo(list(b))
```

and pycharm says `foo` expects a `List[str]` but got `List[Tuple[str, ...]]` instead. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The `Tuple` annotation is implicitly added to `*args`, so in your code `b` is a `Tuple[Tuple[str, ...], ...]`. Instead you should have:

```
def bar(*b: str):
  # b is Tuple[str, ...]
  return foo(list(b))
```